# Flink doesn't consume Data from Kafka publisher

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

What I have: http://prntscr.com/szmkn4

That's the most barebone version of it. Some stuff's gonna come later, but for now the issue is that data is properly arriving in my consumer in form of a JSON string.

I want to throw it into a flink table, which I create with this statement: http://prntscr.com/szmll3

I then check if it got created, just to be sure and get this: http://prntscr.com/szmn79

Next I wanna turn on the machine and check my data with "SELECT * FROM RawData" and get the following error:

- [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
  org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

I assume it's an issue with how I created my table, but am honestly not sure where/what/how.

My publisher's properties in NiFi are:

https://prnt.sc/szoe6z
and
http://prntscr.com/szoeka

If you need any additional information from me, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance,

Psy

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-consuming-data-from-Kafka-using-consumeKafka-0-10/td-p/174254

Comment: I am using the correct Kafkabroker as you can see in my screenshots. (https://prnt.sc/szmll3 and https://prnt.sc/szoe6z)

Answer (score 0):

> [ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason: org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers

That likely means that the Kafka bootstrap servers you've specified to Flink cannot have their hostnames resolved on the Flink servers. You'd know if it's a NiFi issue because you'd see errors in the NiFi flow saying it couldn't produce to Kafka. It might be producing to the wrong topic or even the wrong set of brokers if you have multiple Kafka clusters, but the error you posted isn't a NiFi issue.